# unique entry inherits entities symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am working with two classes:
employee and physician.

doctor class inherits employed.

How could put a restriction to not use any email could ever recorded in employee? Each email must be unique in the two classes.

for class employee I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="tipo1", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"empleado" = "Empleado","medico" = "Medico"})
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"dni"}, message="Este valor ya se ha utilizado.")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="Este valor ya se ha utilizado.")
* @UniqueEntity(fields={"username"}, message="Este valor ya se ha utilizado.")
 */
```

but do not extend to the class as a doctor also.
thanks.

Comment: assert work perfectly when i register employee with email the doctor but if i register doctor with email employee no work validation.